# How to get original DataColumn value from DataRow?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I have a DataTable and i want to figure out the Original column value for all the modified  data rows.

I am using following approach to get the Orginal column value before the DataRow was modified

```
DataRow[] dataRowArray = dataTableInstance.Select(null,null,DataViewRowState.OriginalRows);
DataRow originalDataRow = dataRowArray[rowIndex][columnIndex, DataRowVersion.Original]
```

Please point out what am I doing wrong here ? Above code does not give me the Original column , instead it gives me the latest modified column value.

Thanks.
Nikhil

Comment: I have the same problem, never call AcceptChanges but still the originalrows contain the modified values, not the original. Have you ever found a solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Original values are lost when you call `AcceptChanges` (which is usually called when you call `Update` on a `DataAdapter` or `TableAdapter` too). Once the changes are accepted, you  can't access the original values, that's probably why your code doesn't work.

Comment: i am not explicitly calling any update on my data table. I am actually using third party Grid control to which my data table is assigned. May be the grid does some manipulation on the underlying datasource!!

Answer (score 0):

```
DataRow row = undefinedrow;   
row["Column"].ToString();
```

this returns the value converted to a String of the Column devined.