# How to enable a button that is disabled based on textBox? c#

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I got a textBox that load value from my database and a button that update changes based on the value of the textBox. What I need is to enabled the button if the textBox value changed. For example, the value that the textBox loads is 3 if I also input again 3 in the textBox the button will still be disable. The button will only enabled if I changed the value for example to 4 or any number but not 3.

Comment: Please post the code that you are using to do this.

Comment: @Anthony Sorry but I did not understand "Cache the original value somewhere then compare in the TextChanged Event".

Comment: Basically you compare the current textbox value with what the original value was set to. If you have a datatable, you might look at this question, or one similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756965/how-to-get-original-datacolumn-value-from-datarow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cache the original value somewhere then compare in the TextChanged Event

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == OriginalValue)
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;
        }
        else 
        {
            button1.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

Alternatively, you could just do this (see CodesInChaos' comment below):

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = textBox1.Text != OriginalValue;
    }
```

Comment: why the `if` statement instead of an assignment? I'd simply use `button1.Enabled = textBox1.Text != OriginalValue`

Comment: @CodesInChaos Yes, that is a good way to do it. I often use tighter code in my own projects, but here, often, you need to have good readability so people fully understand what is going on. Especially with a question like this.

Comment: How i will cache? OriginalValue = textBox1.Text; Something like that?

Comment: I wouldn't do that. You could just use a variable like I have above, or you could look at the original value of a field in a datarow. Depending on how you get the data, it may or may not make sense to store the original value in a member variable.

Comment: IntelliSense suggests the last code in the post, works as expected. Its just a shortcut for a long ternary statement.